# how to create temp table based on column number?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to create a temp table based on number of columns?

for example if count is 20 create a temp table with 20 columns (all are nvarchar types).

If count is 10, then create temp table with 10 columns only.

Comment: Count of what? Number of columns where? Have you considered using `SELECT * INTO` so that your `CREATE TABLE` doesn't have to be dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **REALLY REALLY** want to do this as written, you can use dynamic SQL like below:

```
DECLARE @ColCount int = 20
DECLARE @Ct int = 1
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE #VarTemp('

WHILE @Ct < @ColCount+1
BEGIN
    SET @SQL += 'Col' + CAST(@Ct as nvarchar(8)) + ' nvarchar(256),'
    SET @Ct = @Ct + 1
END
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, (LEN(@SQL) - 1))
SET @SQL += ')'

SELECT @SQL
```

Just put the outputted SQL string into another window, or if you trust it you  can change the `SELECT` to an `EXEC`.

Comment: tried with 'EXEC @sql' getting error 'The name 'CREATE TABLE #VarTemp(Col1 nvarchar(256),Col2 nvarchar(256),--' is not a valid identifier.
'.

Comment: @James123 Wrap it in parentheses: `EXEC (@SQL)`.  It's trying to find a stored proc named `CREATE TABLE....` otherwise.

Comment: How to insert into this temp table I tried like 'INSERT into #VarTemp EXEC sp_FindStringInTable 'Nareshbhai%', 'dbo', 'aspnet_Membership'' error I can see ' Invalid object name '#VarTemp'.'

Comment: @James123 THat's a separate question you need to ask.  It's probably a scoping issue.